# Floyd's cycle detection algo, is the if(slow_ptr!=NULL) check required in the code

Tags: c, linked-list

hi i came across this piece of code that implements floyds cycle detection algorithm,and was wondering if the check `slow_ptr!=Null` was required because `slow_ptr` is traversing only those nodes that fast pointer either traversed or skipped(after checking if it was non-NULL,that is), so isn't the check `if(fast!=Null&&fast->next!=NULL)` necessary and sufficient?

here is the code

```
int detectloop(struct node *list)
{
  struct node  *slow_p = list, *fast_p = list;

  while(slow_p && fast_p &&
          fast_p->next )
  {
    slow_p = slow_p->next;
    fast_p  = fast_p->next->next;
    if (slow_p == fast_p)
    {
       printf("Found Loop");
       return 1;
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the code you've posted check for `slow_p != NULL` is redundant.